# Currently I am working in a BLDC motor control, Can you tell me how to control the Angle of the motor?

Tags: matlab, simulation

We should not use any type of simscape blocks in the MATLAB
The motor should be controlled through PID controller
Now I am build the dynamic model of the motor and it is fed with the sine blocks

I have to control the angular position of the  motor by using the PID controller